# How do you upload a downloadable Azure DevOps marketplace extension?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, devops

[image]

I cannot work out how to upload this SNYK extension for Azure DevOps that I downloaded from the Marketplace. It did not offer any other options than downloading, and it then showed these instructions. However, I do not understand them and cannot seem to implement them.

I added /_gallery/manage to the URL I found on the first page of settings. That caused a 404 error. Is this not the correct URL?

I went to the manage extensions page that can be accessed from the same top-right of screen shopping bag button as the marketplace and leads to settings, there is no option to upload. I cannot find any instructions for uploading a downloadable extension and I don't see any options allowing for it. Where can I find the upload button?

Does anyone know what this screenshot is trying to indicate to me to do?

Comment: The download is specifically for Azure DevOps *Server*, the on-premise self-hosted version of Azure DevOps. To install the extension into the cloud-version of Azure DevOps, make sure you're logged in with the exact same account and active directory tennant as your Azure DevOps instance. You should then get an option to either request the extension from an administrator or install it yourself if you have the required permissions

Comment: In case you want to install into Azure DevOps Server, either initiate the marketplace from the manage extensions page or by uploading it into the local marketplace.

Answer (score 0):

After you install any Extension in Azure DevOps, You can utilize it in your release pipeline and start creating tasks and triggers.

***To Install the Snyk Extension, I went to my Azure DevOps organization > Organization Settings > Extensions on left***

[image]

[image]

Clicked on Get it Free this routed me to my Azure DevOps Organization. ***Make sure you open this in the next tab of the browser as your Azure DevOps login.***

[image]

[image]

Clicked on Proceed to the organization, **And the Extension will be added to your Azure DevOps Organization.** Now I created one Service Connection with this extension like below:-

[image]

[image]

You can get the API token from your Snyk account by logging into [snyk.io](http://snyk.io) like below:-

[image]

To build tasks or triggers with snyk in Azure DevOps, you can visit > Pipelines tab in Azure DevOps organization > click on Edit pipeline and add a Snyk task like below:-

[image]

[image]

YAML code added as below:-

```yaml
# Starter pipeline

# Start with a minimal pipeline that you can customize to build and deploy your code.

# Add steps that build, run tests, deploy, and more:

# https://aka.ms/yaml

  

trigger:

- main

  

pool:

vmImage: ubuntu-latest

  

variables:

- group: SharedVariables

  

steps:

- script: |

echo $(databaseserverpassword)

- task: SnykSecurityScan@1

inputs:

serviceConnectionEndpoint: 'sidsnyk'

testType: 'app'

monitorWhen: 'always'

failOnIssues: true
```

Ran the pipeline like below:-

[image]

[image]

You can set Fail on issues to false in your yaml pipeline to run the snyk:-

```yaml
- task: SnykSecurityScan@1

inputs:

serviceConnectionEndpoint: 'sidsnyk'

testType: 'app'

monitorWhen: 'always'

failOnIssues: false
```

You can also run Snyk tasks directly from Release pipeline like below:-

[image]

[image]

[image]

Reference:-

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Snyk.snyk-security-scan

https://snyk.io/blog/building-security-into-your-azure-devops-pipeline/